# Different 3D mesh densities for multiple sharp edges/features? I.e. graded tet-mesh densities

Tags: c++, cgal

I need to have graded 3D mesh densities (from polyhedral object(s) OFF, not image). I'm making good progress with "domain.detect_features();" but all edges then have same density (first criteria fedge i think). For example here (fig below) is a simple cylinder result. What I want is finer mesh at the top of the cylinder, or ideally control mesh density for both lower and upper (or every) 1-d polyline.

Is that possible? I hope I haven't missed something obvious I'm new to cpp/cgal. FYI I'm just using the simple cpp example polyhedra with features.

Thank you for any help/info.
[image]

using latest ver 4.14 working well.

Comment: Did you look at [this section](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/#title27)?

Comment: Huh, no answers at all... oh well.